# pyqgis: Get the Click on canvas standalone app

Tags: pyqgis-3, pyqt5, standalone, mouse-position

I added a subwindow in a MDI area containing a **QgsMapCanvas**. 
Defined the clic tool **QgsMapToolEmitPoint**.

But when I click on the canvas there's no response, al least it should print 'clicked'.
¿¿May be something is missing??
(debug with pycharm on windows)

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *

from resources.main2 import *

class myMainClass(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, ):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myMainClass, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.swMap = QgsMapCanvas()
        self.swMap.setCanvasColor(Qt.white)
        self.swMap.enableAntiAliasing(True)
        self.swMap.setSelectionColor(QColor(255, 255, 0, 50))
        self.ui.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.swMap)

        pointTool = QgsMapToolEmitPoint(self.swMap)
        pointTool.canvasClicked.connect(self.changeColor)
        self.swMap.setMapTool(pointTool)

    def changeColor(self,point, mouse_button):
        print('clicked')
        if mouse_button == Qt.RightButton:
            self.swMap.setCanvasColor(Qt.Red)
        if mouse_button == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.swMap.setCanvasColor(Qt.Blue)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('start')

    app = QgsApplication([], True)
    app.initQgis()
    myapp = myMainClass()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The class main2.py

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(258, 137)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.mdiArea = QtWidgets.QMdiArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.mdiArea.setObjectName("mdiArea")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.mdiArea)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 258, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionOpenSubWin = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpenSubWin.setObjectName("actionOpenSubWin")

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.actionOpenSubWin.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "OpenSubWin"))
```

Comment: I see that changeColor is missing "self" as the first parameter!

Comment: I edited the code, added the 'self', but the behaviour is exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

the issue was on **pointTool** that needed to be part of the *self*

```py
self.pointTool = QgsMapToolEmitPoint(self.swMap)
self.pointTool.canvasClicked.connect(self.changeColor)
self.swMap.setMapTool(self.pointTool)
```